# I need help about a speech recognition code

Tags: c#

Firstly sorry for my bad english but I'll try to explain where I get error. I'm trying to make something like Speech Recognition Bot. I'm watching a video on youtube about it.

While he writes "sRecognize.SpeechRecognized +=" he clicks "Tab" button and it adds "sRecognize_SpeechRecognized" after the "=".

But when I clicked Tab, it adds "new EventHandler< SpeechRecognizedEventArgs >(sRecognize_SpeechRecognized);"

Anybody can help me what should I do?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
   {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    SpeechRecognizer sRecognize = new SpeechRecognizer();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sRecognize.SpeechRecognized +=new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sRecognize_SpeechRecognized);
   }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney thanks for your reply but it's not working :/

Comment: It's due to a different version of Visual Studio.  Older versions use the verbose syntax that includes `new EventHandler...` - newer versions just put the name of the event handler and let the compiler infer the delegate type.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it myself now, thanks for your try :)

Comment: @LaraCroft You should post the answer to your own question, for future people experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @xvan I added the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I fixed it.

I just added `sRecognize_SpeechRecognized` after "+="

and wrote the code below.

```
void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Result.Text.ToString() + " ");
        }
```

Finally, it looks like this and works fine.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SpeechRecognizer sRecognize = new SpeechRecognizer();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;

        }
        void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```